# JSON request on self-signed server with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, json, swift, rpc, nsurlsession

I have a swift based iOS app which make some JSON request on a self-signed server with https connection.

The connection can't be made because of the warning popup you can see when using a browser.

I'm using NSURLSession to do the request, what did I do wrong ?

This is my code :

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let url = NSURL(string: configUrl)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json-rpc", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let requestDictionary = [
            "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
            "id"      : 1,
            "method"  : "myMethod",
            "params"  : ["apikey": jeedomConfig!.apiKey]
        ]

        do {
            let requestBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(requestDictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
            request.HTTPBody = requestBody

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                data, response, error in

                do {
                    //some code
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the error message I get in Xcode :

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Thanks !

Comment: please add error log

Comment: There is no error log. It just does not work, "data" is nil. But if I try the same code with http connexion, everything works.

Comment: is it only on iOS9 if yes you need to add support for NSAppTransportSecurity

Comment: No, the problem is iOS 8 too. I have the "App Transport Security Settings" "Allow Arbitrary Loads" : "yes" in my info.plist

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting back from the browser, than would be very helpful to people trying to solve your problem, screenshot would be fine. It would be great to know what HTTP response code your server is returning.

Comment: When I try to reach the url with a browser, I have a message like this : http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/self-signed-ssl-certificate-warning.

Comment: And when I try to make te JSON request with my app, I have a message in the Xcode console : "NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)".